# What are the differences between ConcurrentQueue and BlockingCollection in .Net?

Tags: .net, generics, c#-4.0

What are the differences between `ConcurrentQueue` and `BlockingCollection` in .Net?

Why `BlockingCollection` is best for producer-consumer operation when it can be done through `ConcurrentQueue`? Do I have to improve anything in the following code?

```
MessageSlotMachineGameStartOrAndStatusUpdate msg;

while (!aCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    try
    {
        this.isStillConsumingMsg = true;
        Boolean takeResult = this.msgQueue.TryTake(out msg, this.msgConsumeTimeOut, aCancellationToken);
        if (takeResult)
        {
            if (msg != null)
            {
                this.ProcessMessage(msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException err)
    {
        EngineManager.AddExceptionLog(err, "Signal Operation Canceled");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        EngineManager.AddExceptionLog(err, "Signal exception");
    }
    finally
    {
        this.isStillConsumingMsg = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: BlockingCollection uses CurrentQueue as the underlying type to hold the data. Plus it has blocking functionality.

Comment: also just note BlockingCollection uses ConcurrentQueue by default, but you can specify another collection type in the constructor that implements  IProducerConsumerCollection...for example if you wanted LIFO you could specify a ConcurrentStack instead

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`BlockingCollection` has a `Take` method that would block the consumer if there is nothing to take, and wait for a producer side to provide an item. `ConcurrentQueue` lacks such method - if it is empty, the consumer would need to handle the wait, and the producer would need to provide a non-empty notification.

Comment: @WAPGuy You can use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). Follow the link and scroll down for an example of how it is used.

Comment: ok,when it signals to WaitHandle? immediately when it is empty or after a timeout given on Take method?

Comment: @WAPGuy It signals right away. The timeout timespan is there to ensure that if there is no signal within the given timeout, the method does not hang forever.

Comment: with regards to order of take? it's FiFO for both?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou By default, `BlockingCollection` wraps a `ConcurrentQueue`, so the answer is "yes". However, you can construct `BlockingCollection` objects with other collections inside them to change the order of "take".

Comment: A good example is you have an unknown endpoint or extremely long wait between producing data for the queue. If you use a concurrent queue instead you can simply halt the process and restart it via another method after the long wait. I don't believe blocking a thread for an extended period of time is a good design.

Answer (score 19):

The **BlockingCollection** is a wrapper for concurrent collections, and the default wrapped collection IS a **ConcurrentQueue** ;-)

From [Microsoft BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8):

> When you create a BlockingCollection object, you can specify not
> only the bounded capacity but also the type of collection to use. For
> example, you could specify a **ConcurrentQueue** object for first in,
> first out (FIFO) behavior, or a **ConcurrentStack** object for last in,
> first out (LIFO) behavior. You can use any collection class that
> implements the **IProducerConsumerCollection** interface.
> **The default collection type for BlockingCollection is ConcurrentQueue.**

The **BlockingCollection** has a **Take()** blocking method (hence the name), but it also has a very interesting **GetConsumingEnumerable()** method which allows you to loop indefinitely : the code will enter the loop inside code only when something is added to collection.
See [albahari.com](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT) excellent online ebook about Threading.

Here is the code sample from this website:

```
public class PCQueue : IDisposable
{
  BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>(); 
  public PCQueue (int workerCount)
  {
    // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
      Task.Factory.StartNew (Consume);
  }
 
  public void Dispose() { _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); }
 
  public void EnqueueTask (Action action) { _taskQ.Add (action); }
 
  void Consume()
  {
    // This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
    // are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called. 
    foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
      action();     // Perform task.
  }
}
```