# c# queue and deque at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, queue, multitasking

i am working on a project that requires read a qr code, queue it, as it is queue another task dequeues the data and send it to machine via socket messaging. this is all done in c#.

my question is how would i keep queue while another task is dequeing. i have the qr code working, i can queue and dequeue and the socket messaging portion working. but i don't know how to run the queue and dequeue at the same time.

i have looked into threading, specifically multi threading. i am more confused than before i started reading.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: So based on you comments and doing a little bit of research, i started writing a bit of code. no matter what i did, the thread only runs once. it is supposed to keep running.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BlockingCollection<string> _queue = new BlockingCollection<string>(30);
    //private string item = "A";
    //private int count = 0;
    private Thread _th1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _th1 = new Thread(thread_example);
        _th1.Start();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void thread_example()
    {
        if (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            _queue.Take();
            Console.WriteLine("Removed 1 Item from queue!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queue Empty!");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    private void btnProduce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _queue.Add("test_string");
        Console.WriteLine("Added 1 item to the queue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between ConcurrentQueue and BlockingCollection in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010748/what-are-the-differences-between-concurrentqueue-and-blockingcollection-in-net)

Comment: _"the thread only runs once. it is supposed to keep running"_ -- if that's so, why didn't you do anything to keep it running? Like, include a loop to allow the thread to keep running? Frankly, your question is too broad...it's clear what you really need is to do some research on your own, to learn about producer/consumer patterns in C#, along with thread synchronization techniques to allow a consumer to wait for new data without consuming CPU time. The `BlockingCollection` class may well be your best choice here, but there's not any way to know for sure, with a question so broad.

Comment: In your example, you have a `thread_example` method, which gets called only one time and then the thread exits. If you expect the consumer to be continuously consuming via `_queue.Take()`, then you need some type of infinite loop inside `thread_example` which would call  `_queue.Take()`. Also your code defeats the blocking feature. Your code should be `private void thread_example() { while (true) { _queue.Take(); Console.WriteLine("Removed 1 Item from queue!"); } }`

Comment: BTW, if you want to notify me with follow ups, you will have to comment on my answer to get my attention. Also, if my answer works for you, then you should upvote it and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview). The problem you have is called a [Producer-Consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)

`BlockingCollection` provides an implementation that handles the `Producer-Consumer` problem.

**Specifically, you have to also think about:** What happens when the dequeuing thread gets slow and can't keep up with the scanning thread, say due to network slowness at that time?

The `BlockingCollection` will block the queuing thread to slow the whole process in sync, based on the `BlockingCollection Capacity specified while constructing`.

Also, you can get either FIFO or LIFO behavior, by using `ConcurrentQueue` or `ConcurrentBag` as the underlying storage. `BlockingCollection` just provides the "bounded-ness" properties on top of the underlying synchronized collections.

Comment: So do you create 2 threads. 1 for produce and 1 for consume. or do you use the default thread and BlockCollection will take care of the multitasking. forgive me for the ignorance. I am trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @melmatvar You need 2 threads one for producer and one for consumer. 1 of these threads could be your main thread, if that works for your application

Comment: thank you for that information. I am going to try that and I will report back.